# Paypal Sandbox Vault: C# The operation has timed out (HTTP request timeout was set to 30000ms)

Tags: c#, httprequest, paypal-sandbox

How do I change the timeout period for a PayPal Vault transaction?  Sometimes it works and other times I keep getting this timeout error even though I'm changing credit card numbers.

I'm using VS 2013 and C#.  I've seen a reference to paypal.config but I don't know where that would be placed or what to put in it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm building the config in code so all I had to do is add:

```
config = new Dictionary<string, string>();
config.Add("connectionTimeout", "120000");
```